# ./configure --with-boost AND --prefix=$HOME/trentacoollime

Tags: configure, boost

I am trying to configure in my /trenta directory which is on a path

```
$HOME/trentacoollime/trenta
```

In order to configure in the trenta directory, I have to include option of

```
--with-boost=../boost.1.51.0
```

otherwise, the `configure` script exits with this error message

```
boost version required >=1.41.0
```

I also have to include

```
--prefix=$HOME/trentacoollime
```

for the sake of my configuration command structure.

How can I use both options at the same time when I run the

```
./configure
```

command script?

Please note that I cannot execute

```
./configure --with-boost=../boost.1.51.0
```

and

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/trentacoollime
```

separately

the former command works, but the latter command does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain arguments. Thus

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/trentacoollime --with-boost=../boost.1.51.0
```

will work.

Space is normally used as the separator between arguments. You can generally add as many arguments as you want.